# SMB extremely slow when rsync from NAS?

Tags: linux, rsync, network-attached-storage, server-message-block, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speeding up rsync over smb](https://serverfault.com/questions/68270/speeding-up-rsync-over-smb)

I started to rsync a mount smb share to a local raid partition yesterday evening. After 12 hours it has copied like 30% of 400 GB... the average speed is 4mb/s, but I connected the both machines directly over ethernet, should have 100 Mbit/s connection...

Any advice how to speed things up?

Edit: the files are many many images and indesign files, creative work!

Answer (score 1):

Copy speed depends more by disk speed (which raid? hardware o software? SCSI, SAS, SATA...) and less by network speed. Usually the bottleneck is always disk side.

Comment: the nas is a MaxData SN40 und the raid controller is a m5015 in a IBM x3500 server with a RAID5 6 SATA drives!

Answer (score 1):

Identifying the actual NAS product in addition to the hardware configuration would help in determining what to expect.